# Bing maps How to set a pin on a map (url)?

Tags: c#, api, bing-maps

I have all the code, the only thing that missing for me is how to put a pushpin in that url:

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&cp=50.22599~50.81103&lvl=10

My pushpin link is:
http://s8.postimg.org/8uuikcaw1/pin.png

I want to make something like this:
http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&cp=50.22599~50.81103&lvl=10&pushpin=http://s8.postimg.org/8uuikcaw1/pin.png

Or if bing maps has their pushpin, it's also good.
Just want to get a static image with a map and a pushpin on it, can someone help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pushpin proposed answers above do not seem to work anymore. The red pins do not appear on the map but the 'cards' are listed and the description appears on the map when the cursor hovers over the card. As mentioned by @vitale232 point collections are an alternative which I used but these don't seem to work either using MS Edge (Chrome) Version 113.0.1774.50 with e.g. point collection url [https://www.bing.com/maps/?sp=point.56.38166_-4.21704_10%3A36_~point.56.38137_-4.21646_10%3A39_&lvl=15&sty=s](https://www.bing.com/maps/?sp=point.56.38166_-4.21704_10%3A36_%7Epoint.56.38137_-4.21646_10%3A39_&lvl=15&sty=s) The points briefly show then disappear so something has changed but there is no update to MS documentation. It seems that MS has added an automatic DB name search once the points are placed and if the names are not recognised the points remain invisible except when the cursor is hovered over each 'card'. So this url works [https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=56.3319444444444~--4.61222222222222&sp=point.56.3319444444444_-4.61222222222222_&lvl=15&sty=s&eo=1&where1=Beinn%20a%27%20Chroin](https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=56.3319444444444%7E--4.61222222222222&sp=point.56.3319444444444_-4.61222222222222_&lvl=15&sty=s&eo=1&where1=Beinn%20a%27%20Chroin) But this does not appear [https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=56.3319444444444~--4.61222222222222&sp=point.56.3319444444444_-4.61222222222222_&lvl=15&sty=s&eo=1&where1=Bong](https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=56.3319444444444%7E--4.61222222222222&sp=point.56.3319444444444_-4.61222222222222_&lvl=15&sty=s&eo=1&where1=Bong) A possible workaround would be to use polyline e.g. https://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?sp=Polyline.47.68_-122.12_48.68_-123.12_49.68_-122.12_LINE_some%20notes_http://bing.com__%2300ff00__4px_Single_Solid Ideally this should be documented properly by MS especially when they change/break something!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community Bot says 'something' is not clear? Please be specific and I will try to improve the post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the latitude and longitude with yours.

```
var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6, -122.33)); 
map.entities.push(pushpin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a map with a pushpin:

[Pushpin in a map](http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&cp=32.04030~34.81179&lvl=15&sp=point.32.0403022766113_34.8117866516113_Gurit%20Kadman%20Tel%20Aviv%20Israel) (with tooltip).

Comment: Doesn't show any pushpin for me, just a "shared places" menu on the right of my map window. Maybe the API behavior is different now?

Comment: I'm getting the desired effect using the [Collections editor and collections parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-a-custom-map-url#collections-editor-and-collections-parameters) portion of the API. Here's an example URL: https://www.bing.com/maps?sp=point.45.23423_-122.1232_Some%20Point_WhereAmI